# Correct java 8 setup for class unloading (Metaspace cleanup) / cxf issue

Tags: java, out-of-memory, cxf, jax-ws, metaspace

I'm creating dynamic CXF clients in my application.

This is the code snippet of client creation:

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory factory = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = factory.createClient("wsdl/hello.wsdl");
```

Now, when I setup test application with this paramters

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/cxf -XX:MetaspaceSize=12m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=24m -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=40 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=sums=200 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/hdump.hprof -XshowSettings -jar classloader-leak.jar
```

and execute client creation in loop, I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace  exception. I don't know why aren't classes unloaded/ metaspace cleaned up. If somebody can help me [here](https://github.com/bilak/classloader-leak) is my testing project. Just build (mvn clean package) it and execute with command line as I did.

I'm using JDK8u77.

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't pass your own `ClassLoader` to  `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.createClient()` and destroy it when done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue in [CXF](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6852). Problem is that URLClassLoader which is created inside JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.createClient() is never destroyed.